# when trying to update records it gives a value of 0 - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update, crud

i am working on a little crud system for adding factories.
but now when i click edit and fill in the form (still empty, because i did not set set_value)
and click submit it gives a value of 0 for all the fields.

i think it has to do with the id but i don't know what the problem is.

My link to the edit page (using id as segment(3))

```
<a href="<?= base_url();?>members/updatebedrijven/<?= $item->idbedrijven;?>">Edit</a>
```

My controller function:

```
function updatebedrijven()
{
    $this->load->view('members/header');
    $this->load->view('members/editform');
    $this->load->view('members/footer');
}

function update()
{
    $this->members_model->updatebedrijf($id);
    redirect('members/index');
}
```

My model function:

```
function updatebedrijf($id)
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array(
       'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'),
       'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'),
       'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'),
       'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'),
       'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
       'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'),
       'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'),
       'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'),
       'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')
    );

    $this->db->where('idbedrijven', $id);
    $this->db->update('bedrijven', $data); 
}
```

my form:

```
<div id="cpanel">
<h2>Bedrijfsgegevens aanpassen</h2>
<?= br(1);?>
<?= validation_errors(); ?>
<?= form_open('members/update');?>
<table>
<b>NAW Gegevens</b>
    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Bedrijfsnaam:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Bedrijfsnaam');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Adres:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Adres');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Postcode:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Postcode');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Plaats:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Plaats');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Telefoonnummer:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Telefoonnummer');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Website:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Website');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Email:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Email');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Profiel:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_textarea('Profiel');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_submit('submit', 'Opslaan');?> <?= form_reset('reset', 'Reset');?></td>
    </tr>


</table>
<?= form_close()?>
<br/>
<a href="<?= base_url();?>members/index"><< Terug</a>

</div>
```

Comment: `$this->members_model->updatebedrijf($id);` this line in `function update()` in controller.... From where `$id` came?

Comment: Probably because your trying to access post data in the model. You should access the post data in your controller, and then pass it to the model.

Comment: So @Jeemusu could you give an example of how to do that?

Comment: You should declare the `$data` array in your controller, then pass it to your model as a parameter of the function `$this->members_model->updatebedrijf($id, $data);`

Comment: i did the same with my addfunction and that worked. but i will try it.

Comment: It may not be the problem. I've seen people use codeigniter like this without problems but I've also seen cases where post data has been inaccessible in the model. Still, if your using an MVC framework you should try to keep to the rules of MVC, which would be accessing the post data in your controller and passing it to the model.

Comment: it did not work. still a value of 0 when i update

Comment: If you were to `print_r($data);die();` before it gets to the `redirect('members/index');` part of the update() function, what output do you get?  Assuming your keeping your post data in the controller, otherwise, try the same at the start of your model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28639/discussion-between-jeemusu-and-kees-sonnema)

Comment: it gives me an array of the names i put in the input field in my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we need to move some of your code around. You shouldn't be accessing the uri, or the post data in your models, so lets move that out to the controllers.

Controller functions:

```
function updatebedrijven()
{
    // Access the uri in the update form and pass the value to the view
    $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $this->load->view('members/header');
    $this->load->view('members/editform', $data);
    $this->load->view('members/footer');
}

function update()
{

    // Access the post data in the function the form is posted to (not the model)
    $data = array(
      'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'),
      'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'),
      'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'),
      'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'),
      'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
      'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'),
      'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'),
      'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'),
      'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')
    );
    $this->members_model->updatebedrijf($id);
    redirect('members/index');
}
```

Model function:

```
function updatebedrijf($id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('idbedrijven', $id);
    $this->db->update('bedrijven', $data); 
}
```

Secondly, your posting the form to `members/update` , when we need to really post it to `members/update/$id` . So lets change the view code a little and include the id variable was passed to it from the controller:

`<?= form_open('members/update/'.$id);?>`